# android read video OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, video, out-of-memory, byte, large-files

I try to read a video file in Xamarin android in order to convert it to string64.

I have success with very small files (3 secondes), but if the file is bigger (1 minute) i have an OutOfMemoryError.

I have try to add android:largeHeap="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in the manifest file and modify my code to read the video file but still the issue.

Failed to allocate a 134217744 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 126MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 94159504, growth limit 201326592.

What i have try:

```
byte[] bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file.AbsolutePath);

string encoded = Base64.EncodeToString(bytes, 0);
return encoded;
```

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(file.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    //var b = ReadToEnd(stream);
    //encoded = Base64.EncodeToString(b, 0);
    //return encoded;
    byte[] bytes;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return base64;
}
```

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.AbsolutePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];

for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.Read(b)) != -1;)
{
      bos.Write(b, 0, readNum);
}

byte[] bytes = bos.ToByteArray();
string encoded = Base64.EncodeToString(bytes, 0);
return encoded;
```

Have you got an idea to fix this or split video file without load it entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to load it in memory first? Play it directly from the video file path

Comment: I don't need to play it. I just want to save datas in a json file to send it by Rest API and then create the file in the server side.

Comment: Ah ok so probably you can pslit the video, send it over multiple files and  merge them on the server

Comment: @user1343960 How are you creating the file? Is it via PHP?

Comment: Can i split the video without load the entire file?

Comment: The video file is create directly by the camera on the phone